# Как выключить скрипт из тега <head> если ширина экрана привышает 200px?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Условие написал но как выключить эту строчку при ширине больше 200px

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

не знаю.

```js
var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
if (width > 200) {
  alert(width);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/themes/landing/script.responsive.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

Заверните его в див. Присвойте диву класс. В стилях в разделе через вьюпорт если <200 ширина экрана устройства пропишите этот класс как display:none а в обычном подразделе пропишите как display:block!important

```
<div class="ubrat"><script>Тело скрипта</script></div>
```

В CSS

```
.ubrat{display:block;}

@media only screen and (max-width:210px) {
.ubrat{display:none!important;}
}
```

Comment: Эм.. Скрипты и так невидимы. Ему не это надо.

Comment: зачем мне в див заключать если мне нужно выключить загрузку скрипта на тех устрояствах на которых он не нужен

Answer (score 0):

Пробуйте так

```
function dhtmlLoadScript(url)
{
   var e = document.createElement("script");
   e.src = url;
   e.type="text/javascript";
   document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e); 
}

var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
if (width < 200) {
  dhtmlLoadScript("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js");
}
```

Comment: а как именно тот удалить <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>?? у меня ведь несколько скриптов в heade.

Comment: куда можно его url подставить?

Comment: не пишите его, тут код добавления, если ширина меньше 200.

Comment: а все увидел, благодарю, попробую

Comment: скрипт благополучно работает. Проверяю ошибок в коде нет

Answer (score 0):

Вы его можете удалить со страницы, но так как он был загружен в память, там он и останется и тут вроде как уже ничего не поделаешь.